# Changing dialog boxes

Tags: c++, winapi

win32 API:

So let's say I have a dialog box with 2 menu items, "Menu Item A" and "Menu Item B"

When I click "Menu Item A" I want the main screen of the current dialog to change to dialog A's screen

When I click "Menu Item B" I want the main screen of the current dialog to change to dialog B's screen.

How would I do this?  I'm new to the win32 api, thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have dialog resources which define the controls for dialog A and dialog B? or are you creating all the controls for the dialog screens manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to have two child 'container' dialogs as children of your outer frame window; let's call them dialogA and dialogB. These contain the controls for the two respective dialogs. When you want to switch from one to the other, use ShowWindow() to show one dialog and hide the other. In Win32, hiding a HWND also hides all the child controls with it, so you can easily hide and show groups of controls by grouping them in sub-windows like this.

That's an overview of the general technique. As for the sub-dialogs, you can either create them manually using CreateWindow(), or use CreateDialog() to have windows do the work of creating the child controls from a dialog template for you.

This technique is essentially what property sheets and wizards do. (Property sheets add a tab control instead of menus to control which gets displayed, while wizards have next/prev buttons.)

Comment: So basically if you provide a parent, the child window/dialog is displayed inside its parent, and the position is relative to the parent?

Comment: Correct; when you position a child window (one that has WS_CHILD style) using CreateWindow or SetWindowPos, the coordinates are interpreted as relative to the parent.